# SAAJ API for sending SOAP response

Tags: soap, saaj

How can we use SAAJ API for creating and sending SOAP response to client .most examples in the net are for sending request from client to server

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I found in the net:

http://itdoc.hitachi.co.jp/manuals/3020/30203Y2310e/EY230155.HTM#ID00260